# Comparing string pointer with other pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

i am comparing string pointer with other pointer
but string pointer gives error while writing this code

i tried printing element using string pointer
but actually gets error

```
int main()
{
   string s="abcde";
   string *sh=&s;
   cout<<sh[2]<<" "<<s[2]<<endl;
}


RESULT -ERROR
```

Comment: Please update your question to provide a [mre]. The code in your question will not compile because it doesn't `#include` any headers, so `string` and `cout` are undefined. I can *guess* that `string` is `std::string`, but it's not clear. Also, you didn't show us the error message. I'll add a "c++" (always include a tag specifying the language you're using). Finally, "CPP" refers to the C Preprocessor; the language is "C++".

Comment: Oh, and your title refers to comparing string pointers, but there are no comparisons in your code.

Comment: What's the benefit of comparing pointers?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The sh variable in your code is a pointer of strings, not chars as the string content. It does not mean the same thing as s[2] because s is a string the [] operator will access its third element.
When you access sh[2] you are accessing the third **string** address from the start of the "array of strings" represented by sh as a pointer. As you don't have this kind of data this access is invalid.